# Executing Arc Program in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, turtle-graphics

I have wrote Arc Program that use TurtleWorld to execute. I get the result right. But in serious issue, can I reduce the code & can someone explain me the code that i have wrote. I didn't get the concept. This program was in the exercise session of my book

```
from swampy.TurtleWorld import *
world = TurtleWorld()
bob = Turtle()

def arc(t=bob, r=50, angle=360):
    arc_length = 2 * 3.14 * r * angle / 360
    n = int(arc_length / 3) + 1
    step_length = arc_length / n
    step_angle = float(angle) / n
    for i in range(n):
        fd(t, step_length)
        lt(t, step_angle)

arc()
wait_for_user()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please highlight 2 or 3 things/lines that are particularly unclear to you.

Comment: Commands like `lt` and `rt` are explained here: http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/swampy/TurtleWorld.html